# In Neovim, swap 3 key pairs

Tags: lua, neovim

I use the dvorak keyboard layout and am trying to get into using the neovim text editor (AstroNvim).

To keep on using the home row navigation that I'm used to (from elsewhere), I would like to swap 3 key pairs in normal mode:

- <kbd>t</kbd> <--> <kbd>k</kbd>
- <kbd>n</kbd> <--> <kbd>j</kbd>
- <kbd>s</kbd> <--> <kbd>l</kbd>

Meaning, when in normal mode, <kbd>t</kbd> should be mapped to <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd> should be mapped to <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> should be mapped to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, ...

**Is there a light-weight way to accomplish this?**

---

**Remark 1:**

I'm aware many users consider it easier to just learn where the nav keys are on the dvorak keyboard, but that's not what I'm interested in doing.

**Remark 2:**

I could add remappings to the beginning of AstroNvim [`mappings.lua`](https://github.com/AstroNvim/AstroNvim/blob/main/lua/astronvim/mappings.lua) config file like so:

```lua
maps.n["t"] = { "k", desc = "swapping t and k" }
maps.n["k"] = { "t", desc = "swapping t and k" }
maps.n["T"] = { "K", desc = "swapping t and k" }
...
```

but there are 2 issues with this:

1. There are many remappings, if all the modifier combinations need to be considered as well, so there would be many lines; and
2. AstroNvim has additional remappings that will override mine. For example, on line 23 of AstroNvim's [`mappings.lua`](https://github.com/AstroNvim/AstroNvim/blob/main/lua/astronvim/mappings.lua):

   ```lua
   maps.n["k"] = { "v:count ? 'k' : 'gk'", expr = true, desc = "Move c ursor up" }
   ```

   I would rather not have to touch the default AstroNvim config, but instead *only* add a single remapping config file of my own, which is run either before or after the config files that AstroNvim provides.

Answer (score 0):

Astro seems to apply user overrides preferentially over its defaults [lua source](https://github.com/AstroNvim/AstroNvim/blob/main/lua/astronvim/bootstrap.lua#L101).

As such, you can use what you said about declaring them in the astro overrides without issue. To reduce the duplication factor, you can use a small lua snippet to make it more declarative:

```lua
local function swap(tbl)
    for _, set in pairs(tbl) do
        local from, to = unpack(set)
        maps.n[from] = { to, desc = ("swapping %s and %s"):format(from, to)}
        maps.n[to] = { from, desc = ("swapping %s and %s"):format(to, from)}
    end
end

swap {
    { 'n', 'j'},
    { 't', 'k'},
    { 's', 'l'},
}
```

This approach also allows you to expand these pairs in the future, if you so desire.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Amy. With user-mappings taking preference, though, wouldn't this snippet de-activate the line 23 of AstroNvim's [`mappings.lua`](https://github.com/AstroNvim/AstroNvim/blob/main/lua/astronvim/mappings.lua) that I mentioned in my question? (`maps.n["k"] = { "v:count ? 'k' : 'gk'", expr = true, desc = "Move c ursor up" }`)

Comment: Adding your own bind will override astro's, yes. I am not sure how else you would want to go about it? If you did not override it, the bind would not work, because astro's binds would remain.

If you wanted to fetch the existing astro bind, you could do something like this:
`maps.n[from] = maps.n[to]`

Comment: I'm not sure either - I can imagine there exists a way to "chain" remappings. Such that, my personal config defines a remapping from t -> k, and then astronvim's config remaps that to something (slightly) different. If this is not possible, I'll have to sift through and change astronvim's config, which I want to avoid; this is why I asked the question.

Comment: Your changes will always override astro's, but you can fetch the value that astro sets, as I detailed above. "chained" mappings are not a thing with neovim, unless you implement them as such in lua, but I do not think that is needed here.